# MuseScore 2 closed after launched

Tags: 16.10, musescore

My MuseScore 2 worked well in Ubuntu 16.04, but, after I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10, a problem has developed. Shortly after being launched, it will close automatically by itself. I tried to uninstall it and reinstall it again, but the same problem persists.

I tried to remove it, then reinstall with the commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install musescore
```

Then I got the following message during installation:

```
Failed to start ipmiutil ...
```

What steps can I take to solve this problem?

**EDIT:** I have just tried run it at the command line, and it produced the following error message:

```
initScoreFonts 0x5585aedffa90
Creating interface for ScoreView object
Ignore SSL error: 6 The certificate has expired

(musescore:18563): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplayManager'

(musescore:18563): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(musescore:18563): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
程式記憶體區段錯誤 (核心已转储)
```

Comment: Most likely, if you remove `~/.config/musescore`, the issue is solved. lease mention.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks for your suggestion. I tried, but doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, shoot. The reinstalling is the only option I am afraid. Wait, you already did without succes? That is odd.

Comment: I tried to remove it, and reinstall bysudo add-apt-repository ppa:mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install musescore and got the following message during installation: Failed to start ipmiutil ...

Comment: I am about to freshly install 16.10. Using musescore a lot. I will let you know if it works here.

Comment: How did you reinstall the package? With something akin to `apt-get install --reinstall musescore musecore-common`? Did you [verify the integrity of all installed packages](/q/57704/175814)? Are you aware that there's no package for Yakkety in that PPA? Did you try the [unstable PPA for Yakkety](https://launchpad.net/~mscore-ubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/mscore-nightly?field.series_filter=yakkety)?

Comment: I've uninstalled it in Ubuntu software center and downloaded the Appimage version, but the same problem still persists.

Comment: Have you tried running it in debug mode? (From the terminal with the -d flag) If so, do you get more detailed error messages when it crashes?

Comment: OK I've found the "solution". I launch musescore, then as I said, it will close automatically after a few seconds. OK now launch it again, it will prompt me that the program was terminated unexpectedly last time and ask me whether I want to restore the last session. Choose "no" then the same problem will persist. But choose "yes" to restore the last session, then everything works fine. So the problem is SORT OF solved, only that I need to launch it every time in such a strange way!!

Comment: @velutluna, I'd recommend adding this as an answer / workaround for future users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I've found the "solution". I launch musescore, then as I said, it will close automatically after a few seconds. OK now launch it again, it will prompt me that the program was terminated unexpectedly last time and ask me whether I want to restore the last session. Choose "no" then the same problem will persist. But choose "yes" to restore the last session, then everything works fine. So the problem is SORT OF solved, only that I need to launch it every time in such a strange way!!

Comment: Velut, you can also mark this as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark beside the post.  If someone comes along with a better answer, you can always move the check mark to their anwer.